# Random forest for high dimensional data with repeated measures (the LongituRF package in R)

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, random-forest, panel-data, high-dimensional

I have some high dimensional repeated measures data, and i am interested in fitting random forest model to investigate the suitability and predictive utility of such models. Specifically i am trying to implement the methods in the `LongituRF` package. The methods behind this package are detailed here :

[Capitaine, L., et al. Random forests for high-dimensional longitudinal data. Stat Methods Med Res (2020) doi:10.1177/0962280220946080.](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/0962280220946080)

Conveniently the authors provide some useful data generating functions for testing. So we have

```
install.packages("LongituRF")
library(LongituRF)
```

Let's generate some data with `DataLongGenerator()` which takes as arguments n=sample size, p=number of predictors and G=number of predictors with temporal behavior.

```
my_data <- DataLongGenerator(n=50,p=6,G=6)
```

`my_data` is a list of what you'd expect Y (response vector),
X (matrix of fixed effects predictors), Z (matrix of random-effects predictors),
id (vector of sample identifier) and time (vector of time measurements). To fit random forest model simply

```
model <- REEMforest(X=my_data$X,Y=my_data$Y,Z=my_data$Z,time=my_data$time,
                    id=my_data$id,sto="BM",mtry=2)
```

takes about 50secs here so bear with me

so far so good. Now im clear about all the parameters here except for `Z`. **What is** `Z` **when i go to fit this model on my actual data?**

Looking at `my_data$Z`.

```
dim(my_data$Z)
[1] 471   2
head(my_data$Z)
      [,1]      [,2]
 [1,]    1 1.1128914
 [2,]    1 1.0349287
 [3,]    1 0.7308948
 [4,]    1 1.0976203
 [5,]    1 1.3739856
 [6,]    1 0.6840415
```

Each row of looks like an intercept term (i.e. 1) and values drawn from a uniform distribution `runif()`.

The documentation of `REEMforest()` indicates that "Z   [matrix]: A Nxq matrix containing the q predictor of the random effects." **How is this matrix to be specified when using actual data?**

My understanding is that traditionally Z is simply one-hot (binary) encoding of the group variables (e.g. [as described here](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/introduction-to-linear-mixed-models/)), so `Z` from the `DataLongGenerator()` should be nxG (471x6) sparse matrix no?

Clarity on how to specify the `Z` parameter with actual data would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66188123/implementing-longitudinal-random-forest-with-longiturf-package-in-r). It appears that regardless of Z. "Error in solve.default(S1) : Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular:"
are quite common